# how to fit div columns side by side with scroll?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to position divs side by side, to show comparisions in columns. If the number of columns increase than the viewport size, the columns come down next line. How do I make them fit side by side with horizontal scroll ??

Comment: What do you mean by Horizontal Scroll?

Comment: means if user adds a new column, it should be placed to the right of the current column. Then, it shouldn't run out of horizontal space. you got my point ??

Comment: You coudl try positioning them differently. I assume you are using floats at the moment (posting code of how you are doing it currently would be useful) but if they are fixed width columns then you could just state how far from the left they are (eg the first column would be 0px from the left, the 2nd 200px, the third 400px, etc. maybe... I don't know if this would fit your usage though since there are several assumptions being made (eg fixed width columns).

Comment: they are fixed width column, 200px, i should be giving 1st at 2px, 2nd at 210px, etc counting the margins too then..  will try and let you know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this is what you are asking for.

http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/XYq2U/1/

Comment: one column is coming down ?? if you add 2 more columns it is doing 3 cols in one row and 2 in other.

Comment: Oh you dont want any columns... but there is going to be maximum width limit, atleast body width

Comment: Check this http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/XYq2U/2/ It will extend up to screen resolution

Comment: Check this http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/XYq2U/3/. It have manually defined a limit, to extend the division up to 1000%; so until that is filled up, no column will fall down.

Comment: The main point is, there needs to have a limit. unless, you reside for some scripting.

Comment: your last attempt looks good, "almost" what I want, but it would be "exactly" from "almost" when you make viewport size dynamic..  That is, if you make it resize automatically to fit the columns :)                [ps : I am currently using jquery to resize them on condition, dynamically, I am trying to find out if any easy css solution is available to reduce the javascript ]

Comment: @Shrinath, if you are using jquery to resize the container, stick to it. There is no other better solution. However, script or CSS, there need to be a limit, there is no such thing as unlimited Width.

Comment: :) I am trying to squeeze out as much performance as possible, because there are lot of other computations done on the javascript which are already taking time.. So thought I'd check if there is a way to do this with css..

Comment: And I didn't mean to ask for unlimited width, I wanted to ask for dynamic size.. sorry about that

Comment: Dynamic size, go serverside or javascript